# Made sure content-type and content-encoding, still get 415 Unsupported media type

Tags: http, retrofit2, okhttp

In my application, I am sending request with *okhttp3* and *retrofit2*. Here is I logged the request by `HttpLoggingInterceptor`:

```
  okhttp3.OkHttpClient: --> POST https://something/here http/1.1
  okhttp3.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  okhttp3.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 2596
  okhttp3.OkHttpClient: --> END POST (2596-byte body)
```

And I have this in my server:

```
@Consumes("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```

Currently, Keep getting HTTP 415 error code.

Environment:

- RedHat
- Retrofit:2.3.0
- Okhttp:3.8
- Logging-interceptor:3.8

Comment: FWIW; there's no charset param on application/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only the @Produce type should match the @Consumes type, but also the @Body should be completely matched.